# JAX-RS How to choose image mimetype?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

Is there any way to select the very best `Accept` mimetype for image manipulation?

I have a resource looks like this.

```java
@GET
@Produces({"image/jpeg", "image/png"})
public Response readResizedImage(
    @Context Request request,
    @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
    @QueryParam("width") final int width,
    @QueryParam("height") final int height) {

    final List<Variant> variants = Variant.mediaTypes(
        new MediaType("image", "jpeg"), new MediaType("image", "png")).build();

    // Why on earth variants is empty?
    if (!variants.isEmpty()) {
        final Variant variant = request.selectVariant(variants);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "{0}", variant.getMediaType().toString());
    }

    final List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes =
        httpHeaders.getAcceptableMediaTypes();
    for (MediaType acceptableMediaType : acceptableMediaTypes) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "acceptableMediaType:{0}/{1}",
                   new Object[]{acceptableMediaType.getType(),
                                acceptableMediaType.getSubtype()});
    }

    return null;
}
```

I tried this resource with following command.

```
$ curl -v -H "Accept: */*" \
-H "Accept: image/*;q=0.2" \
-H "Accept: image/jpeg;q=0.5" \
-H "Accept: image/png;q=1.0" \
http://.............
```

And server prints

```
acceptableMediaType:image/png
acceptableMediaType:*/*
acceptableMediaType:image/jpeg
acceptableMediaType:image/*
```

QUESTION:

**How can I select a proper (not wildcarded) mime type?**

I must have one for manipulating image bytes for re-sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easiest if you leave this up to Jersey - i.e. have 2 methods, one producing image/png, other producing image/jpeg. Jersey will call the right one depending on the quality parameter of individual media types in the accept header of the incoming request.

Comment: See the JAX-RS spec (http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/edr/jsr339/index3.html) section 3.8